# Perl: Iterating through this funky array?

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to iterate over a 2D array that is structured in this specific way.  Whether or not this is a good way to structure the array is another question - I still need to be able to iterate over it (if it is possible).

```
@row1 = ( "Current Scan", "Last Month");
@row2 = ( "240", "0");
@row3 = ( "226", "209");
@row4 = ( "215", "207");

@array = (\@row1, \@row2, \@row3, \@row4);
print Dumper(@array);
printarray(@array);
```

Dumper gives me the following output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Current Scan',
          'Last Month'
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          '240',
          '0'
        ];
$VAR3 = [
          '226',
          '209'
        ];
$VAR4 = [
          '215',
          '207'
        ];
```

I've tried several for loops with no success.  Each only prints the first row ($VAR1) and quits.  Here is my most recent attempt:

```
sub printarray {
  @array = shift;
  $rowi = 0;
  foreach my $row (@array) {
    for (my $coli = 0; $coli <= @$row; $coli++) {
      print "$array[$rowi][$coli]\n";
    }
    $rowi++;
  }
}
```

I'm obviously overlooking something simple.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what result do you expect, but there is an error in using `length` function. You don't need it, because it returns length of the string. Use `$coli < @$row` for loop condition.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it to hopefully make it a bit more clear.  I'm basically just trying to iterate through the entire array, and for some reason it is only going through the first row.

Comment: I left out a very important part I think.  At first I thought it was just me screwing up the iteration, but I had forgot I was passing it through a subroutine...  I'm guessing that's the problem...

Comment: Yep, that's the root of the problem. Thanks for adding that clarification!

Comment: Silly me focusing on the wrong problem.  Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: @Magicked => in your `printarray` sub, be sure to use `my` when declaring `@array` and `$rowi`, otherwise you are referring to the package global variables.  `use strict;` at the top of your code to catch these for you.

Comment: You are using data dumper wrong.  Remember that Perl expands arrays in function arguments into lists, so if you want a dump of your top level array, you need to use `print Dumper \@array;` instead of what you have.  Perl's list expansion makes normal function calls akin to Lisp functions called with the APPLY function.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apply for more info.

Comment: Also, see perllol and perldsc in the perldoc for examples of working with common data structures.  See http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want just print the array, try following code:

```
foreach my $row (@array) {
   foreach my $elem (@$row) {
       print $elem; ## print elements without separator
   }
   print "\n"; ## new line after row
}
```

If you need indexes for some purpose, here we go:

```
for(my $row_i = 0; $row_i < @array; $row_i++) {
    for(my $column_i = 0; $column_i < @{ $array[$row_i] }; $column_i++) {
        print $array[$row_i][$column_i];
    }
}
```

The idea is that `@array` in *scalar context* returns number of elements in array. And `@{ $array[$row_i] }` is a little more tricky. It dereference array stored in `$array[$row_i]`.

**Update for subroutine:**

In perl you can pass array by reference:

```
 printarray(\@array); ## pass reference

 sub printarray {
     my $array_ref = shift; ## no copy created

     foreach my $row (@$array_ref) { ## now we need to dereference
         ...
     }
 }
```

You can also pass a copy of array:

```
 printarray(@array);

 sub printarray {
     my @array_copy = @_; ## store local copy of array
     ...
 }
```

For more details take a look at [How can I pass/return a {Function, FileHandle, Array, Hash, Method, Regex}?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-can-I-pass%2freturn-a-%7bFunction%2c-FileHandle%2c-Array%2c-Hash%2c-Method%2c-Regex%7d%3f) manual page.

And please add **`use strict;`** at the begining of programm. It'll force you to declare all variables, but will save bunch of time if you type something incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks.  I left out an even more important part above.  I was so focused on the iteration portion that I forgot I had passed it through a subroutine...  I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass the array into the subroutine, you're essentially passing in eight scalars. Then, when you do

```
sub printarray {
  @array = shift;
```

... you're popping off only the first element in the list. Try:

```
sub printarray {
  @array = @_;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   use warnings;
   use strict;

   my @row1 = ( "Current Scan", "Last Month");
   my @row2 = ( "240", "0");
   my @row3 = ( "226", "209");
   my @row4 = ( "215", "207");

   my @array = (\@row1, \@row2, \@row3, \@row4);

   foreach my $row (@array) {
     foreach my $value (@$row) {
        print "$value\n";
     }
   }
```

This will print

```
  Current Scan
  Last Month
  240
  0
  226
  209
  215
  207
```

Not sure if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is in the way you're passing the array to the subroutine.  Perl flattens arrays in parameter lists.  Basically, `printarray(@array)` is (in this example) equivalent to `printarray($array[0], $array[1], $array[2], $array[3])`.  The `shift` at the beginning of `printarray` takes the first parameter and assigns it to `@array`.  So no matter how big the array is, `printarray` only sees the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Algorithm::Loops 'MapCar';

my @row1 = ( "Current Scan", "Last Month");
my @row2 = ( "240", "0");
my @row3 = ( "226", "209");
my @row4 = ( "215", "207");

my @array = (\@row1, \@row2, \@row3, \@row4);

MapCar { print "Scan: $_[0]: $_[1], $_[2], $_[3]\n" } @array;
```